# Form validation in an HTA file

Tags: validation, hta

How can I perform a simple validation on this HTA form to make sure that data is inputted and an option is selected? This should be simple, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any answers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<html><head><title>Write data to text file</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION 
border="thin" 
borderStyle="normal" 
caption="yes" 
maximizeButton="no" 
minimizeButton="yes" 
showInTaskbar="yes" 
innerBorder="yes"
navigable="yes"
scroll="auto"
scrollFlat="yes" />


<script language="javascript">
window.resizeTo(480,150)


function Writedata()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


var write_id;
write_id = document.getElementById('write_id').value ;

alert('The data has been written to \n' + write_id);
var s = fso.OpenTextFile(write_id, 8, true);

s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('name_id').value);


s.Close();
}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<h3>Input some information</h3>
<form>
<td>Input: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name_id"></td>

<td><select id="write_id">
  <option name="write" value="">Select an Option</option>
  <option name="write" value="C:\temp\option1.txt">Option1</option>
  <option name="write" value="C:\temp\option2.txt">Option2</option>
</select></td>

<td><input type="button" onclick="Writedata()" value="submit"></td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can find [`select.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) and [`input.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) at MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stumped, so I rewrote this in vbscript.

I have included bits of what I did to give you an idea of how to write to a text file, and validate your form with an HTA.

The vbscript:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strSender = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" ) ' Get the current Username


Dim Checkmark

Sub Validate

If form.Flag.checked = True Then ' Find out if your Checkbox is checked
    Checkmark = "*"
Else
    Checkmark = ""
End IF

If form.field1.value = "" Then                    ' Validate the form
    alert "Please enter an number!", "0", "Title"
ElseIf IsNumeric(form.field1.value) = False Then
    alert "Please enter a valid number!", "0", "Title"
ElseIf form.drop_down1.Value = "" Then
    alert "Please select a save location!", "0", "Title"
ElseIf form.field1.value < 100000 Then
    alert "Please enter a six digit number!", "0", "Title"
ElseIf form.field1.value > 999999 Then
    alert "Please enter a six digit number!", "0", "Title"
Else
    SaveData
End If

End Sub


Sub SaveData                    ' Write data to a text file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(form.drop_down1.Value) Then
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(form.drop_down1.Value, 8)
    strLine = form.field1.value & vbtab & Checkmark & vbtab & strSender  & vbtab & Now ' fields that will be written
    objFile.WriteLine strLine
    MsgBox "The Information was successfully written to the file.", "0", "Title"
    objFile.Close
Else
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(form.drop_down1.Value) ' If file does not exist, create file
    strLine = form.field1.value & vbtab & Checkmark & vbtab & strSender  & vbtab & Now
    objFile.WriteLine strLine
    MsgBox "The Information was successfully written to the file.", "0", "Title"
    objFile.Close
End If
End Sub
```

The HTML:

```
<form name="form">
<h2>Imput</h2>
<tr><td><lable>Data: </lable></td><td><input type="text" name="field1" size="25"></td>    </tr>
<tr><td><lable>Save Location: </lable></td><td><select name="drop_down1">
<option type="text" name="select" value="">Select an option</option>
<option type="text" value="SavePath1...">SavePath1</option>
<option type="text" value="SavePath2...">SavePath2</option>
<option type="text" value="SavePath3...">SavePath3</option>
</select></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="Flag" value="">Flag *</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="Validate">
<input type='reset' id='ResetFields' value='Clear Fields' />
</form>
```